# Allowing Certain Users To See/Search Certain Records Only

Tags: administration, permissions, sharing

I believe this functionality is built into SF, but I am not familiar with it and our company may be needing it soon.

How do I allow certain users to only be able to see (or search) specific records?  If we have 200,000 leads and 50,000 accounts, and they are only supposed to be able to see Leads with Field X = 123 or Accounts with Field Y = 456, how would this be accomplished (especially in searches so they don't see any OTHER records)?

Thanks.   *UPDATE:*  If there are multiple methods, I'd be interested in knowing them so I can make the best decision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would take some time to read over [Salesforce's Sharing documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm). Sharing in Salesforce is usually one of the more difficult things to grasp when working with the platform.

A way to do this particular instance would be to have the Account and Lead objects set up as private in your [org wide defaults](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_sharing.htm). You can then share access to these objects using [Sharing Rules](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/security_about_sharing_rules.htm) that are criteria based.

I will note however that this method may not be the most optimized way to do it for a large organization. It may be much better to properly set up a [role hierarchy](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_roles.htm) with ownership. Using Sharing Rules you will need to set up each user on each rule specifically. Role Hierarchy will handle all of this for you by simply being in the correct role.

Comment: Roles..? Really?  Interesting, because I already have taken the time and effort to cleanup our roles (before the need of allowing "outsiders" access' came about).  I like that thought and am going to pursue it.   Thanks!